# Voice command in Android activity

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition

I have an activity in my app that has a counter for 2 different teams, now, to add a point to this teams I need to click a button. 
I want to do this also with a voice command.

The thing is that I need: offline voice recognition, add points but not restart the activity, wait continuously for another voice command, only work in one Activity.

And the language will be Spanish.

Do you know any way to do this?
I have been searching and find PocketSphinx, but I don't know if this is the best option.

Comment: First of all check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it, and **YES**, is posible with PocketSphinx.
I had to edit the code but [this page](https://www.vladmarton.com/pocketsphinx-continuous-speech-recognition-android-tutorial/) was very helpul.